# How do i set variables literally in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, youtube-dl

I want to set `"var3=%(title)s.%(ext)s"`
But windows keeps on interpreting 
`%(title)s.%(ext)s`
as 
`(ext)s`
instead of
`%(title)s.%(ext)`
is there a way to "set" in a literal way without cmd interpreting it?

*EDIT* Somebody wanted to see the whole script

```
cd C:\youtube-dl
youtube-dl -U 
echo Remember to press enter only AFTER update is complete
pause
set /p "var1=Enter URL: " %=% pause
set "var2=%date:/=-%" 
set /p var3=%(title)s.%(ext)s
youtube-dl "%var1%" -ci -o C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Music\Download_dl\%var2%\%var3% -f best -x --    no-mtime --add-metadata --write-thumbnail  
cd C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Music\Download_dl\%var2%
del *.mp4
```

Comment: Did you want to prompt for var3?  `set /p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve most special characters in batch, enclose them within quotations. This will prevent most from being lost or translated into their special meaning.  However, for `%` in batch files, it must be escaped by itself `%%`.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\youtube-dl
youtube-dl -U
echo Remember to press enter only AFTER update is complete
pause
set /p "var1=Enter URL: " %=% pause
if defined var1 set "var1=%var1:"=%"
set "var2=%date:/=-%"
set "var3=%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"
youtube-dl "%var1%" -ci -o "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Music\Download_dl\%var2%\%var3%" -f best -x --    no-mtime --add-metadata --write-thumbnail  
cd "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Music\Download_dl\%var2%"
del *.mp4
endlocal
```

Changes

- scoped variables with setlocal/endlocal
- removed poison character quotation from user input
- enclosed literal strings in quotations

Comment: Why did you "@echo off" "setlocal" and "if defined var1 set "var1=%var1: "=% though? Sorry i'm new to this... But the script works  now

Comment: The `@echo off` prevents the commands from displaying when running, `setlocal` is good practice to limit your variables to your script and not affect the current running session of the command line, and `if defined var1 set "var1=%var1:"=%"` removes double quotation characters (if any) from the user input to prevent a script crash.

Comment: Sorry i didn't quite understand how the if defined... function worked

Comment: @user3407161 `if defined var1` checks to see if the variable is empty, `set "var1=%var1:"=%"` sets the variable var1 to the value of the expression, `%var1:"=%` does a character replace on the value of var1 replacing double quotations for nothing `"=` (blank after the equal).  Summary: if var1 is not empty, remove all double quotations and save it back into var1.

Answer (score 2):

In batch files, `%` has special meanings. In your code

```
set "var3=%(title)s.%(ext)s"
          ^.........^
```

the indicated percent signs are delimiting the name of a variable called `(title)s.`. And this variable is not defined (i suppose from your output), so what you get is

```
set "var3=(ext)s"
```

You need to escape the percent signs to get the desired result

```
set "var3=%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"
```

Comment: This is what happens when i use that                                                         [Input] C:\Users\Admin>set "var3=%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"

C:\Users\Admin>%var3%
'%%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user3407161  Please show your whole script.  Are you just calling `%var3%` as a command?  If you want to display its value you need to use `echo %var3%`; otherwise, the command line is trying to execute the value of `%var3%`.

Comment: @user3407161, the code posted is intended for usage in batch files. From command line, the double percentage signs are not needed. Anyway, in the new posted code, changin your `set /p var3=...` into `set "var3=%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"` and changing to `-o "c:\...."` (with quotes) should solve the problems.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann I'm trying to use it as a part of **bold** C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Music\Download_dl\%var2%\%var3%